# Asymptotic analysis of a given code

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

I have been given the following pseudocode:

```
 j = 1
 while j < n:
      k = 2
      while k < n:
           k = k*k
      j++
```

In my thinking, this piece of pseudocode would have the following complexity:

```
 O(n*log(n))
```

Since the outer loop is executing n times. While the inner loop is essentially splitting the increment step by half each time. Is my thinking too far off?

edit: 1 more (these aren't homeworks, I promise, just examples to understand)

```
 for i = 1 to n:
    for j = 1 to n:
       k = j*j
       while k < n:
          k++
```

In this instance, the outermost loop will execute n times. The middle loop will also execute n times, putting us now at n<sup>2</sup> times. The innermost loop, as I under stand it will execute log(n) times, putting us at O(n<sup>2</sup>*log(n)) times. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you sure you've written the pseudocode correctly? The way I see this there's an out loop of size n and an inner loop starts of size n-1, so this should be O(n^2). 
I've made the assumption that k++ in the inner loop and that "do something" is O(1).

Comment: What is "do something" doing?

Comment: @Mitchel0022 do something just means do whatever you do in the loop. Edited to remove it

Comment: @idnavid I originally wrote out wrong. Fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `O (n log log n)`.

The outer loop just repeats the inner loop `n` times as far as time is concerned, so it contributes a multiplier of `n`.

The inner loop is trickier, it does repeated squaring of `k`.
See how it goes:
`2^1 -> 2^2 -> 2^4 -> 2^8 -> 2^16 -> 2^32 -> ...`
So, for example, if `n = 2^32`, the loop will have `5` iterations.
Here, `log_2 (n)` is `32`, and `log_2 (32)` is `5`.

Generally, if `n = 2^(2^r)`, the inner loop will arrive at `n` after `r` iterations.
By taking the logarithm, we arrive at `log n = 2^r`.
By taking the logarithm another time, we have `log log n = r`.
As you probably know, the base of the logarithm is not important when dealing with asymptotic behavior, as long as it is constant.

So, we have `n` iterations of a loop which itself makes `log log n` iterations, making the overall complexity `O (n log log n)`.

Comment: A bit counter-intuitive at first, but makes sense. How would this be re-written such that it is nlogn? What would the step be?

Comment: @basil replace `k = k*k` with `k = k*2`or any other constant > 1 for that matter

Comment: I added one more example, is my understanding correct there?

Comment: @basil If you have a new question, do post it as a separate question.

Comment: @basil The addition is sufficiently different. And you give no reasoning for your own take at the answer ("The innermost loop, as I under stand it will execute log(n) times"). Perhaps try to find such reasoning, and if you don't succeed, post it as a separate question. In any case, please remove the addition from the question to keep things consistent.

Comment: I just mean any op. I will change the for loop, to a while loop for increased understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would be right, the first loop is straight forward as O(n). The second part is a bit more tricky. Im going to use reason rather than rigor to show its O(logn).

So lets assume for a second its `k = k * 2`. This a familiar sequence that we know as `O(logn)` however we see that `k >= 2` for any given loop so we know that the sequence `k = k*k` will be bounded above by `O(logn)`, that is it is at *most* O(logn). It is easy to see that it is not `O(1)` so we know O(1) is a lower bound. Take it together to get `O(nlogn)`

Comment: While it is true that there is an upper bound O (n log n), the tighter bound is O (n log log n), as shown in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
O(n log(n))
```

k^log(n) is exactly the value where k will be equal or greater than n.

> log(n) = x       means 2^x = n

you run the loop n times.

so the complexity is O(n * log(n))